# Programatically position a scollbar of a div relative to its parent container

Tags: html, css

I need to programatically position a scollbar of a div relative to its parent container.

```css
.outerContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.innerContainer {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div>abcdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>abcd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently to see the horizontal scrollbar of the `innerContainer`, I need to scroll down to the last line in the `outerContainer`.

However, I need to fix the `innerContainer`'s horizontal scrollbar position so that I don't have to scroll down the `outerContainer` to the last line in order to see it (preferably would be located at the top).

No matter what the scroll position of the `outerContainer`, my `innerContainer`'s horizontal scrollbar should be always visible.

Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/khh5k197/

Comment: there shouldn't be 100px width to .innerContainer and add the propery overflow scroll to div

Comment: i just need to change the position of the scrollbar of innerContainer to somewhere else where i can see it always ...

Comment: instead  of giving overflow to outer container, give it to inner only.. like this https://jsfiddle.net/khh5k197/2/?

Comment: @Amit, i dont need a horizontal scroll on outercontainer, i just need to bring up the innerContainer's scrollbar programatically to the top

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/khh5k197/3/ this what you wanted ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy .. thank you but not this ....

Comment: ohh i see what you wanted from the accepted answer, i must not have understood the question, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to do it programatically, you just need to get the `overflow` in the right place. Here's your x scroll near the `long-line`:

```css
.outerContainer{
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.innerContainer{width: 100px}
div {width: 200px}
.long-line {overflow: auto}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div class="long-line"> abcdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
    <div> abcd </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

### Edit

Rereading your question, I noticed that you wanted this `innerContainer` scrollbar to be always visible, even if you scroll down the `outerContainer`.

Unfortunately that is not an option, since scrollbars belong to a certain element and are always located at the bottom and right (unless you use `direction: rtl`) positions, when you scroll the `outerContainer`, the `innerContainer` has no choice on the matter (to put it simply :).

However, you can use a plugin like [this one](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) to recreate the scrollbars entirely, giving you more freedom in what you can do and where you can place them... You may need to tweak it though.

Comment: sure that i cannot get hold of the scrollbar using jquery and apply relative position to it and then place it at a certain x,y position  ?

Comment: @jayanthCoder that would be cool to do... Unfortunately the scrollbar is just part of the element, which means most CSS rules for elements do not apply to it... The `direction: rtl` alters its position from **r**ight **t**o **l**eft, but only because the entire element is set to that direction (the text will also start at the right). I believe the best way to achieve these kind of customizations is to [recreate them from scratch](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) (since the default ones are very limited).